# create cx_Oracle arrayvar for DATETIME

Tags: python, datetime, cx-oracle

I want to create a cx_Oracle arrayvar for datetime, wihch I can then use to feed callproc. So the code I expect is something like this:

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012/07/30 10:42:09', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
dt2 = ...(another datetime value)...
av1 = cursor.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.DATETIME, [dt1, dt2])
av2 = ...(another arrayvar)...
cursor.callproc('my_db_procedure', (av1, av2))
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'my_db_procedure'
```

Can someone point out what I was doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I found out what was wrong. In my PL/SQL code I defined the input parameter type as:

```
TYPE id IS TABLE OF varchar2(16);
```

which should actually be:

```
TYPE id IS TABLE OF varchar2(16) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

I hope this could help someone with similar issue.

Comment: I can't solve in my case I use that as a parameter into a stored procedure, How would be in a stored procedure parameter?